# Disadvantages of ntfs-3g `big_writes` mount option

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

[`man ntfs-3g`](https://manned.org/ntfs-3g) makes the `big_writes` mount option seem like a Good Thing:

```
   big_writes
          This option prevents fuse from splitting write buffers into 4K
          chunks, enabling big write buffers to be transferred from the
          application in a single step (up to some system limit, generally
          128K bytes).
```

No down sides are listed... when would I want to avoid mounting with  `big_writes`?

Answer (score 8):

It's a good question, really. From what I can see here there's probably no downsides to it.

Back in 2008 when `big_writes` was [first added to FUSE](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/78bb6cb9a890d3d50ca3b02fce9223d3e734ab9b) Miklos said:

> Prior to 2.6.26 fuse only supported single page write requests.  In theory all
>   fuse filesystem should be able support bigger than 4k writes, as there's
>   nothing in the API to prevent it.  **Unfortunately there's a known case in
>   NTFS-3G where big writes cause filesystem corruption.**  There could also be
>   other filesystems, where the lack of testing with big write requests would
>   result in bugs.
>
> To prevent such problems on a kernel upgrade, disable big writes by default,
>   but let filesystems set a flag to turn it on.

The specific problem is documented in NTFS-3G's `param.h` as:

> ```
> /*
>  *        Use of big write buffers
>  *
>  *    With small volumes, the cluster allocator may fail to allocate
>  *    enough clusters when the volume is nearly full. At most a run
>  *    can be allocated per bitmap chunk. So, there is a danger when the
>  *    number of chunks (capacity/(32768*clsiz)) is less than the number
>  *    of clusters in the biggest write buffer (131072/clsiz). Hence
>  *    a safe minimal capacity is 4GB
>  */
>
> #define SAFE_CAPACITY_FOR_BIG_WRITES 0x100000000LL
> ```

And currently it does defend against this limit by verifying that the fs capacity is at least 4GB before requesting big_writes. So it is safe.

In fact, Tuxera [recommends turning it on](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#slow) if NTFS-3G is eating up your CPU:

> Workaround: using the mount option “big_writes” generally reduces the CPU usage, provided the software requesting the writes supports big blocks.

#### The future

Since [libfuse 3.0.0](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/ChangeLog.rst#libfuse-300-2016-12-08) (2016) `big_writes` is always on:

> The `-o big_writes` mount option has been removed. It is now always active. File systems that want to limit the size of write requests should use the `-o max_write=<N>` option instead. [commit](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/commit/97f4a9cb4fc69be5c3b4d7631ebe20355bdc83dc)

However, libfuse3 is a whole new generation, and ntfs-3g does not support building against it at all. I did inadvently backport the new 1MiB write buffer (libfuse 3.6.0) into ntfs-3g's internal mini libfuse2, so if you want to use that you can grab it from here:

1. https://github.com/AOSC-Dev/ntfs-3g/commit/96f6fbedaf7aad70b4a4c39d8dd4a637a63beec1
2. https://github.com/AOSC-Dev/ntfs-3g/commit/6aa576ae2a13fb636bff65bcb2701e731d2f5a94

Yes, I did remember to refactor the write size / volume size limit. And yes, it is faster with big file writes even on modern Ryzen.

PS: I am planning to add libfuse3 support to ntfs-3g, but there's no real deadline for it. Tuxera is demonstrably not interested in such a change, and coming up with a name for a fork is a bit too much for me.

Comment: >coming up with a name for a fork is a bit too much for me

How about ntfs-lte? ;)

Comment: Hello, was you able to upstream this patches?

Comment: @Bogdan Mart big_writes, yes; fuse3, no. The good news is that they've moved the development to GitHub and is much more active now.